# Magento 2 how to do multi sorting of product on product list page

Tags: magento-2.1, product-list, sorting

In magento 2 by default we can sort product by product attribute, but we can do sorting with only one attribute at a time. I need to do sorting on multiple attributes.

If anyone know how can i achieve then please let me know.